# Epiphany or Gnome Brower not displaying search results on late 2016 Macbook Pro running in virtual machine through Parallel Desktop Lite

Tags: macbook, epiphany

I have been reading that Linux in general does not run well on the late 2016 MacBook Pro.  I have been running several distros with minimal problems through the Parallel Desktop Lite app, including Elementary, but when I try to use Epiphany, it THINKS it gives me results, in the ALL category, but nothing is displayed. A blank screen.   Is this the incompatibility of the hardware or is there a way to get Ephiphany or any Gnome browser to work?  Firefox runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

This was previously reported at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1480554

Parallels is probably missing some OpenGL extension expected by WebKit. If you want to debug this further, you're going to have to report a bug upstream, at https://bugs.webkit.org/. Prefix the bug title with [GTK] and select the 'WebKit Gtk' Bugzilla component to make sure it gets seen. Ask for help with debugging the issue. Important: run the 'glxinfo' command within Parallels and paste the output. Also look for any command line warnings that might be printed when running epiphany from the command line.

For a workaround, try running it from the command line with this environment variable set:

$ WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 epiphany

and see if that works.